# why local costmap rotates with robot

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi: I got a strange problem. I am simulating a robot in gazebo and visualizing in rviz. My local costmap rotates as robot traverses along its planned path. I tried all options, double check with frames naming. Please refer to an image below.[image: image description]

costmap configuration files are as follow:

**costmap_common_params_sim.yaml**

```
footprint: [[-0.18,-0.20],[-0.28,-0.10],[-0.28,0.10],[-0.18,0.20],[0.070,0.20],[0.180,0.10],[0.180,-0.10],[0.07,-0.20]]    
inflation_radius: 0.75
cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
transform_tolerance: 2.0

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor sonar_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_scan_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan,marking: true, clearing: true, obstacle_range: 10, raytrace_range: 10}

sonar_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /myscan, marking: false, clearing: true, obstacle_range: 5.2, raytrace_range: 5.7, observation_persistence: 0}

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_scan_link, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /marking, max_obstacle_height: 7, min_obstacle_height: 2, marking: true, clearing: false, obstacle_range: 4.9, raytrace_range: 4.9, observation_persistance: 0}
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  map_type: costmap
  unknown_cost_value: 1
  track_unknown_space: true
  obstacle_range: 10.0
  raytrace_range: 10.0
  update_frequency: 0.5
  publish_frequency: 0.2
  static_map: true
```

**local_costmap_params.yaml**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  map_type: costmap
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  obstacle_range: 2.0
  raytrace_range: 2.0
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  inflation_radius: 0.35
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  origin_x: 0.0
  origin_y: 0.0
  resolution: 0.025
```

I am just using laser sensor to get the data in simulation. So "sonar_scan_sensor" and "point_cloud_sensor" in costmap_common_params_sim.yaml are not in use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11375/why-local-costmap-rotates-with-robot/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-10-05**:
Have you looked at TF information in rviz? Specifically, you'd want to look at whether the odometric frame moves as expected relative to the map frame. If you see it rotate strangely, something is wrong in your odometry.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-10-01**:
Could you include your costmap configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the odometric frame is rotating with respect to the map frame in rviz, it implies that something is wrong with the raw odometry information. You'll probably want to check that the odometry source you're using is operating correctly. Are you using a custom odometry source? Or are you exposing ground truth data from gazebo over tf somehow?

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SHI.ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/25720/shi.zp/) on 2016-03-19**:
So another words about the root cause is the map -> odom tf relation is polluted by the terrible robot odometer output?